# Two examples of a mySQL database structure, which one is more efficient and preserves data integrity?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'm creating a mySQL database for a small blog. This blog will have articles of different "types", like "public interest", "DIY", etc.

My question is about how to organize the database structure: should I create a table for the articles, a table for the types, and a third table that connect the two of them? Or should I just create the first two tables and add a field in the articles table that points out to the id number of the types table?

### Option 1:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(300) NULL,
    body TEXT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE articleType(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    name char(200) NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `articleType` (`name`) VALUES
('public interest'),
('DIY')

CREATE TABLE articlesArticleType (
    ID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    typeID int not null,
    articleID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### Option 2:

```
CREATE TABLE articles(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(300) NULL,
    body TEXT NULL,
    articleType int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE articleType(
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    name char(200) NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `articleType` (`nombre`) VALUES
('public interest'),
('DIY')
```

In the second case I just need two tables. Which way is more efficient and preserves data integrity?

Comment: When posting it's usually best to translate the column names too in any examples to avoid confusion.

Comment: This isn't about "future proof" it's about data integrity. Is it important that the topics are picked from a select list, or is it irrelevant and they could be entered free-form?

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I've changed the names. And you're right! It's data integrity actually, I was lost in translation. I was planning to filled the stuff using a select list., but it's not that relevant

Comment: This is a good example of a problem that depends less on architecture than on the eventual usage characteristics.  If it is important to know in advance (which is unlikely) one could implement both (one each in separate databases), fill each with a few years worth of anticipated fake data and compare performance (or whatever characteristics of concern).    **Or** just choose one and live with it for awhile.  Converting one schema to another is so easy (less than an hour's work) that it benchmarking experiments or test deployment is quite feasible.

Comment: Do you by any chance have article 50?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost it is important to decide on the cardinality of relationship between the 2 tables - `Articles and Types` as it will influence the choice of the tables structure. Broadly there are 3 cardinalities possible:

1. [One to One](https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_45.htm)
2. [One to Many](https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_46.htm)
3. [Many to Many](https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/SoftDevRDS02CD/page_47.htm)

Option 1 will satisfy `One to Many` and `Many to Many` cardinalities while Option 2 will satisfy `One to One` cardinality.

Comment: *Why* is it important to decide that?

Comment: Since here we need to define a relationship between the tables, hence the degree of relationship - cardinality needs to be known before we can select either of the options.